# Can I use logos and names of other companies in my application?

Tags: copyright, european-union

I want to create an app to search flights for different airlines (probably 3-4).

I will not use airlines names (or part of names) in my app name and I will not use airlines logo in my logo.

All I want is to use their logo and their name in my app in a list of results of flights and in different places in the app similar to this.

Also Apple and Google should allow the app for stores (App Store and Play) so I will not get a ban for copyrighting.

I want to know if I am allowed to do this without any contract with airlines and without contacting airlines before. So just to create only by my own without talking to someone.

This will be for European market.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal to use icons from other companies in my app?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/68128/is-it-legal-to-use-icons-from-other-companies-in-my-app)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer - I'm just offering an opinion based on 20+ years of running a UK Ltd and being a news/research junkie (FT, Bloomberg etc).

I believe you can use a logo so long as you are not implying a relationship exists between the two of you.

That is open to interpretation. I suspect you would get a cease and desist letter for a first offence. After that, its anyone's call.